# Checkout Controller method in Opencart

Tags: opencart

I'm using Opencart 1.5.6. I want to modify index function in catalog/controller/checkout/payment_method.php, just for my extension. So, is there any way to override index function ?

Comment: You can either directly modify this method or You can create a vQmod that will *inject* the logic without direct file modification (recommended).

Comment: Yes, I tried with vQmod and override module. Is there something like predispatch method that can help for doing any custom modifications?

Comment: *Is there something like predispatch method* - **no**, this is not Zend framework 2 and it is not even using own events handling. vQmod is the best way You can use in OpenCart (until You run into collisions with other vQmod extensions).